# Replacement Set and Functions - Repeating Number Allowed? (Algebra I Simplistic Q)

Tags: functions

Quick, simplistic question - I apoligize in advance if I am not using correct terminology.

One has a replacement set for x and y of something along the lines of $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.
They must plug each individual value into a function like $y = x^2 + x$.

So they then have this:

\begin{array}{r | c}
x&y=x^2 + x \\
\hline -2 & 2 \\
-1 & 0\\
\bf{0} & \bf{0}\\
1 &2 \\
2 & 6
\end{array}

The question is, are both $x$ and $y$ allowed to be equal to $0$ according to the replacement set?  Or can only either the $x$ or the $y$ be set to equal $0$?  (is this question not clear enough?)

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly fine to get a $0$ for $y$ when you plug a $0$ in for $x$.

Comment: @mapierce271 I understand that it's perfectly ok to get 0 when 0 is plugged in, but, is it considered valid to use 0 twice even though the replacement set only has one 0 on it?  For example, I've been led to believe 0--0 is only valid when you have {-2,-1,0,0,1,2}.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: I think that you should define what you mean by *"replacement set"*.

Comment: Quite honestly, that's something I don't completely understand myself.  I know is that "it is" for all the x and y values.

Comment: I think "replacement set" is the set of $x$-values we're using to come up with the $(x, y = f(x))$ pairs (Ah, "replace" as in "substitute"). OP, repeats are certainly possible, it just means that different $x$-values are generating the same $y$-value, which is perfectly OK.

Comment: In this particular case, the replacement, or, rather, substitution set, is for both X and Y - which is why confusion has arisen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this](http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/1words/r/r26.htm), it appears that the *replacement set* is just the values that you plug into your expression for $x$. They $y$ values don't need to come from the replacemenet set.

Comment: In this particular case, the replacement, or, rather, substitution set, is for both X and Y.

Comment: @pokemonblack1000 To be honest, I have never encountered the term "*replacement set*" before. Googling it, though, is getting me that the replacement set consists *exclusively* of $x$-values. Despite how we are defining "*replacement set*", what you have shown in your post is mathematically correct, which is what is important.

Answer (score 0):

I was reviewing some notes, and have figured out, for any other future students who have stumbled upon this odd question, that it is, in fact, ok to the an 'x' and a 'y' equal to each other when the replacement set for both x and y values only has the value listed once.